# how to implemet "On click" for a button which is in custom list view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I have three buttons in a custom list view, and list view is in a fragment not in an activity, but when I set onclick listner . it throws exception null object reference passed.
custome_list_view.xml

```
        <Button
        android:text="@string/pickUpButtonText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_hight"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#5BA84F"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:id="@+id/button_pickup_list"

        />
```

customeListView.Java

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs, container, false);

    ArrayList<JobListDataProvider> listJobs = GetRequests();
    ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewJobs);
    lv.setAdapter(new JobsListAdapter(getActivity(), listJobs));
    //.....bindind on click....
    Button pickup = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_pickup_list);
    pickup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //......................
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: implement `onClick(..)` in `JobsListAdapter`

Comment: in which method of JobsListAdapter ...
constructor ? or 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
}

Comment: Goto Your CustomAdapter and there implement the functionality
myBtn.setOnClickListener(. . . ){
. . . Your Code Here
}

Comment: ok thanks brother.... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put this code in `JobsListAdapter` in public View onCreateView

```
Button pickup = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_pickup_list);
pickup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //......................
    }
});
```

Comment: brother i got another problem ..if u may help...
Problem : I have a toggle button in activity bar ... I want Click Listener for this button.. what shall i do  ?

Comment: menu.xml
`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/userModeToggle"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_service_toggle"
        />
</menu>
`

Comment: MainActivity.java
`if(id == R.id.userModeToggle){
            userToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"passenger Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText().show;
                    }
                }
            });
        } `

Comment: man post it as question and share me link i will be give you solution

Comment: add your menu.xml and activity where you want implement

Comment: here it is bro....!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020128/i-have-a-toggle-button-in-activity-bar-and-need-to-implement-onclick